# traceIfFalse is it possible to pass a string not "fixed"

Tags: transaction, on-chain

Is this even possible?

```
traceIfFalse  ("A"++show(scriptContextTxInfo)) FoundIt
```

As logging onchain is just possible with this traceIfFalse ... I'm not finding a solution to make that line work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done to debug `Integer`s is to write a function that converts them into a `BuiltinByteString` and then decodeUtf8 it into a `BuiltinString` which is passed to any of the available `trace` functions.

I assume it could work for more complex data as well, but I have not tried that yet.

Example of what I described above:

```
{-# INLINABLE intBS #-}
intBS :: Integer -> BuiltinByteString
intBS i
  | i < 10    = consByteString (48 + i) emptyByteString
  | otherwise = appendByteString (intBS (divide i 10)) (intBS (modulo i 10))


-- ...
    traceIfFalse (decodeUtf8 $ intBS coolInt) $ ...
--...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not possible as the redeemer code is manipulated/examined from within a template haskell splice and you are running into what is called the "template haskell stage restriction".